не открывается http страница django
Хочу выгрузить свой backend проект на серваке, для этого django проект выгрузил на вм linux(Ubuntu), все необходимое установил, исправил все ошибки при соединении с бд, и тут запустил код(python3 manage.py runserver) зпускается сервер на вм но не открывается http страница



очевидно, что процесс http-клиента вы запустили в хост-машине, где никакой процесс не слушает порт 8000 по ip-адресу 127.0.0.1

то есть мне необходимо поменять порт 8000?, если да, то на какой порт необходимо это поменять. А еще надо ли мне как-то менять ip-адрес 127.0.0.1, если публичный ip моего вм 176.109.107.163?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

вам необходимо выставить «наружу» (т.е. в хост-систему) порт, к которому вы хотите обращаться. ну или запускать http-клиент в том же адресном пространстве, в котором вы запускаете процесс python.

теперь открывается ip-адрес вм, однако я теперь вижу такое, буду очень благодарен, если еще раз поможете https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1588845/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-this-resource
